# Using fs on Meteor Server throws error on frontend... but call does what it should on backend... Why?

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs

I want to 
1. upload a file from the frontend
2. send the data to the backend 
3. save it in a folder on the server

1 + 2 are working and 3. is also, though with some complications...

On the server I have the following code in imports/api/bills.js and I call the writefile method from the client. 
The file does get saved and I don't get any errors on the server, but I do get the below error on the client...

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions where people try to use fs in the browser... but that not what I do (right?)

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import {check} from 'meteor/check';

import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import fs from "fs"


export const Bills = new Mongo.Collection('bills');


Meteor.methods({
   'bills.writefile' (blob) {
       fs.writeFile('/Users/mhe/Downloads/tax/binary.png', blob, function(err) {
           // If an error occurred, show it and return
           if(err) return console.error(err);
           // Successfully wrote binary contents to the file!
         });

    },

});
```

Error:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'bills.writefile' TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function
    at MethodInvocation.bills.writefile (bills.js:75)
    at livedata_connection.js:664
    at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (meteor.js?hash=33066830ab46d87e2b249d2780805545e40ce9ba:1196)
    at Connection.apply (livedata_connection.js:653)
    at Connection.call (livedata_connection.js:556)
    at BillEntry.handleFile (BillEntry.js:88)
    at Object.BillEntry.handleForm [as onChange] (BillEntry.js:68)
    at onChange (FileControl.js:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (modules.js?hash=9581e393779a85fee7aad573af1a251d5bed8130:4483)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (modules.js?hash=9581e393779a85fee7aad573af1a251d5bed8130:4533)
```

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of optimistic UI Meteor simulates Methods on the client to fast return values and only discards them if the server behaved different. This is something you never realize in most of the cases.

However your case is such. The client simulation tries to call fs which is not available on the client and thus throws.

You can prevent this by using `isSimulation` inside the method to prevent calling server-only imports.

Example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'example' () {
    if (this.isSimulation) {
      return true // very optimistic
    } else {
       // original code
    }
  }
})
```

See: https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-isSimulation